# How do I install Oracle Linux 6 with the UEK over the Internet?

Tags: linux, installation, oracle

Is it possible to use the Oracle Linux 6 UEK download and download the rest of the OS over the Internet?

I have UEK running.  I selected URL for the Installation Method.  I tried various URLs for Oracle's public yum repositories.  It can never find install.img.

I don't know if I'dm doing things right.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yum repositories are not the same as installable trees. You'll need to contact Oracle for information on what URL to use for a network installation, if there is support for such over the internet.

Comment: What is the UEK for?  I don't understand.

Comment: The UEK is the "Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel". It's just a different kernel that Oracle ships with OEL (Oracle Enterprise Linux).